# Passing scroll of uitableview in tableview inside uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've got a `UITableView` ( let it be big table view ) with two cells. The second cell has `UITableView` inside. I want to scroll down first cell, than, when it hides from screen on top, i want to disable scroll on the big table view and enable scrolling on the second cell with table view. And when the second table view scrolls to top - enable scrolling on big table view. Here is the link to video :

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwOrFKDV23k3RXBRc215R2dlTnc/view?usp=sharing)

I've implemented it, but with lag - when scrolling of big table finishes, the transition to scrolling of second cell's table isn't smooth. Did anyone implement this before ? Or can you suggest any github help?) Thanks

Comment: Any specific reason for two UITableViews? You can take a single table view with 2 sections with 1 row in each section. The section header gets stuck at the top till the row is scrolled out completely.The blue portion which gets sticks to top will be part of second header view. In tableView:viewForHeaderInSection return view with height 0 for first header.

Comment: @SHN there is. Because second cell contains UICollectionView with pagingEnabled = true and there is also horizontal scroll inside it. In each UICollectionView cell there is a table with dynamic height. So, the idea is to scroll second cell fullscreen, and than to scroll it's content fully up and down. When table scrolls totaly on top, big table scroll turns on